# Cannot GET / NodeJS - Heroku - ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, backend, contact-form

i'm having trouble with deploying my app (new to NodeJS), its all working well on my machine, but i'm getting an error from heroku when trying to enter the app

> Cannot GET /

My only BE logic is connected to the form in my Contact.js component 
I've tried to find different solutions but nothing seems to work..

Folder structure

```
reactapp (FE folder)
 ..build
   ..index.html
 ..src
   ..components
     ..pages
       ..Contact
         ..Contact.js

node_modules
.env
.gitignore
Index.js
package.json
Procfile
```

Contact.js (logic)

```
  async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "", message: "", isClicked: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isClicked: false });
    }, 1000);
    document.querySelector(".form").reset();
    const { name, message, email } = this.state;
    const form = await axios.post("/api/form", {
      name,
      email,
      message
    });
  }
```

Index.js (BE)

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/api/form", (req, res) => {
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    const htmlEmail = `
  <h3>####</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>###: ${req.body.name}</li>
    <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>####</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
      }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
      to: "#######@gmail.com",
      replyTo: req.body.email,
      subject: "######",
      text: req.body.message,
      html: htmlEmail
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Message sent: %s", info.message);
        console.log("Message URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      }
    });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm start start --prefix reactapp",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.2",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^2.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku run npm install in the main folder, but you also have to run it in the reactapp folder. I suggest adding this on your package.json:

`"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix reactapp && npm run build --prefix reactapp"`

if you don't need to build your react app yo can avoid using `npm run build --prefix reactapp"`

Comment: In the client script, you've written "start" twice, could that be the problem?